# Spring JSP view with 2 Forms - each form to diffrent Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, view

I have JSP view and inside 2 Forms, I have 2 Controllers (1 - UserController, 2 - Home Controller)

UserController - Manage all login and regestration to the site
Home Controller - Manage all the User actions

- When i tried to work in **One** Controller it works greate, but when I split the methods to spesific Controller (HomeController) I have error

Why is that?
* The home is called from **UserController** and the actions inside needed to sent to **HomeController**

**Update**

home.jsp -> The form that need to sign to "HomeController"
* it include 2 forms (1-"scanRequest" > UserController, 2-"scanForm" > HomeController)

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/scanRequest" modelAttribute="scanForm" class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create new scan: </h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <spring:bind path="seller_name">
                    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                        <form:input type="text" path="seller_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Seller Name" autofocus="true"></form:input>
                        <form:errors path="seller_name"></form:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="scanForm" value="${UserRequestDTO}" />
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Scan</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

<form:form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/scanTest" modelAttribute="scanTestForm" class="form-signin">
    <h3>${msg}</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="scanTestForm" value="${UserRequestDTO}" />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Test</button>
</form:form>
```

**HomeController:**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @ModelAttribute("scanTestForm")
    public UserRequestDTO getScanForm(){
      return new UserRequestDTO();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/scanTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String scanRequest(@ModelAttribute("scanTestForm")UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        String strMsg = "-----------scanTest---------- \r\n";

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            return "home";
        }


        model.addAttribute("msg", strMsg);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
  @ModelAttribute("scanForm")
    public UserRequestDTO getScanForm(){
      return new UserRequestDTO();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/scanRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String scanRequest(@ModelAttribute("scanForm")UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        logger.info("scanRequest():");

        String strMsg = "---------------------- \r\n" + userRequestDTO.getSeller_name() + "\r\n";

        // Checking if there is any errors with the seller
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            return "home";
        }

        model.addAttribute("msg", strMsg);

        return "home";
    }
```

** I just what it to work and after that I can continue my code..
 **Update: Error - when I cliced on "Test" button **

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

יול 26, 2016 2:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [searcher] in context with path [/Searcher] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at line 47

44:             <table>
45:                 <tr>
46:                     <td>
47:                         <spring:bind path="seller_name">
48:                             <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
49:                                 <form:input type="text" path="seller_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Seller Name" autofocus="true"></form:input>
50:                                 <form:errors path="seller_name"></form:errors>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'scanForm' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag.doStartTagInternal(BindTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAw
```

Comment: *Does not work* or *I start getting errors* is helpless. Say exactly what error and give a stacktrace if you can.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added it now

Comment: What does UserController look like? I only see one form. Where's another form?

Comment: Your errror is stating `scanForm` is unknown on jsp. Did you send any value from controller?

Comment: @Tin I added all the data to my qeustion. The first Form is sent from UserController that it manage all the login & regestration to the site, HomeController needed to manage all the user actions **after** he loged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more details it is easier to understand what has happened - even if there are still dark sides like how have you first displayed `home.jsp`. But here we are:

- you managed to display `home.jsp` (how ?)
- you click on `Test` button
- browser sends a post request to `/scanTest` processed by `HomeController.scanRequest`
- the controller finds in Model an attribute `scanTestForm` built from the POSTed parameters, adds a `msg` attribute and forwards that to view `home` (I assume it is `home.jsp`)
- tomcat starts home.jsp to build the response with `scanTestForm` and `msg` as request attributes - but no `scanForm` because the controller has not added it into the model...
- `<form:form ... modelAttribute="scanForm" ...>` looks for a `scanForm` attribute in the request, finds none and raises an error

How to fix:

- quick and dirty: just add `model.addAttribute("scanForm", userRequestDTO);` in the controller. It will be found by the JSP and should be enough to go past this error
- more correct: instead of just forwarding to the view after the post, to a redirect to the controller that you first used to display `home.jsp`. This is the [post-redirect-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. You can even pass model attributes directly to the other controller by using `redirectAttributes`

But anyway, I cannot understand why you use 2 different model attribute names in the same page if they should use same value at response building time. Because the modelAttribute name is only use at that time, when the JSP build the response, and not when the browser sends back the POST request.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a full Answer. You right.. I tried to add in the same view 2 action to diffrent controllers. I think that you first suggestion was solved my problem. what I dont understand is the "redirectAttribute" in Post method